# Nuxt.js Vuetify v-img component not generating img tag

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with vuetify.
it's not generating a "img" tag, instead it's generating a "div" tag with "background-image" set to the image path.

```
<v-img
      v-if="index === 0"
      :key="index"
      :alt="ticket.name"
      :src="image.thumbnail_images.large || '/images/icons/no_picture.jpg'"
      :width="isPWA ? '' : $vuetify.breakpoint.lgOnly ? 250 : 280"
      aspect-ratio="2"
      height="212"
      lazy-src="/images/icons/no_picture.jpg"
    />
```

this is what i have in my component

```
<div class="v-image__image v-image__image--cover" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.3click.com/UploadedFiles/1019.jpg&quot;); background-position: center center;"></div>
```

and this is what's generating

Comment: v-img actually works with background-image css property, it doesn't have the option to generate img tag as far as I know

Comment: @hamidniakan what component should i use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [line](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L119) in source code vuetify uses the image as background:

```
        style: {
          backgroundImage: backgroundImage.join(', '),
          backgroundPosition: this.position,
        },
```

if you want to use an image as element just use the html `img` tag.